# Optimization of getRange / Copy methods

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to speed up my script, below is a snippet (it's actually a lot longer, but essentially the same thing: getrange -> copy to another sheet.

The issue is I run into execution time issues, I believe I need to minimize the function calls and get the entire range/values in one hit, then copy in another.

Only thing is I'm a script noob and can't work this part out, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function testEV1() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test');            
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Datastore');            
  var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow()+1;
 
  if (sheet1.getRange('B3') != " ")
    var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Confirmation required','Are you sure you want to submit this evaluation?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (confirm == 'ok') { 
    var wait = Browser.msgBox('Submission In Progress', 'Submission will take approximately 15 seconds, please wait for notification.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    /*** Evaluation Details ***/ 
    sheet1.getRange('B2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 1), {contentsOnly: true});                /*** Agent ***/
    sheet1.getRange('B3').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 2), {contentsOnly: true});               /*** Date of Review ***/
    sheet1.getRange('B4').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 3), {contentsOnly: true});               /*** Date of Call or Chat ***/
    sheet1.getRange('D3').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 4), {contentsOnly: true});               /*** Reviewer ***/
    sheet1.getRange('D4').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 5), {contentsOnly:true});               /*** Method of Enquiry ***/
    sheet1.getRange('B5').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 6), {contentsOnly: true});               /*** Type(Issue vs Query) ***/
    sheet1.getRange('B7').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 7), {contentsOnly: true});               /*** Chat & Call Link ***/
    sheet1.getRange('D5').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 8), {contentsOnly: true});               /*** Category ***/
    sheet1.getRange('B6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 9), {contentsOnly: true});               /*** FOFC ***/
    sheet1.getRange('D6').copyTo(sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 10), {contentsOnly: true});               /*** If FOFC NO ***/
    
    var complete = Browser.msgBox('Submission Completed', 'Evaluation has been submitted, you may now clear the form or exit the application.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting your 2 source values all at once & the put those values into a single array to then paste into the sheet. e.g.

```
function testEV1() {
   var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test');            
   var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Datastore');            
   var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow()+1;

   if (sheet1.getRange('B3') != " "){
     var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Confirmation required','Are you sure you want to submit this evaluation?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
   }
   if(confirm=='ok') { 
       var wait = Browser.msgBox('Submission In Progress','Submission will take approximately 15 seconds, please wait for notification.', Browser.Buttons.OK);

       /*** Evaluation Details ***/ 
       // Get all of the values in one query & then order them at the output stage. This gives more data than we actually consume, but it saves in expensive calls to getRange() & getValues()
       var vals = sheet1.getRange('B2:D7').getValues(); // gets a 2D array of the values in the range.
       var dest_range = sheet2.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 10); // the destination range: start at last_row:col_1 & make a range 1 row deep, 10 cols wide.
       dest_range.setValues([
                             [vals[0][0], vals[0][1], vals[0][2], vals[2][1], vals[2][2], vals[0][3], vals[0][5], vals[2][3], vals[0][4], vals[2][4]]
                            ]); // this is your 1 x 10 array of values

       Browser.msgBox('Submission Completed','Evaluation has been submitted, you may now clear the form or exit the application.', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
};
```

This should give you a starting point for a much better implementation.

Comment: This will copy and paste contents of Column C also.

Comment: No, it won't, because it only uses the values from columns B & D (`vals[0]` & `vals[2]`) in the call that sets the values in the destination sheet.  It doesn;t use any values from column C.

Comment: Then why get the unnecessary values from C column, there must be another way to do it :)

Comment: True, you could get 2 ranges, one for each column, but this would add another `getRange().getValues()` call. I made the choice to do one call to get all the values in the range that covers both sets of populated cells, rather than one call for B2:B7 & one call for D3:D6.  Yes, there's unused data in the resulting set, but there's one less call to `getRange()` & `getValues()`

Comment: Correct, but wouldn't this operation increase the size of an array considering there could be (for example) more than 200,000 rows

Comment: In which case, yes you might want to make that optimisation. As i said, my code is a starting point, illustrating the concept of grabbing the values from directly & working with them, rather than making piecemeal calls to `getValues()` or `getRange()` or `copyTo()`. Had the OP mentioned anything like the scale you're suggesting, i would have approached the problem differently, but i stand by the basic concept of getting the data __en masse__ & pasting it __en masse__